# When I use the opencv function cvNorm(image,NULL,CV_L2)，it returns an abnormal result,why?

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, opencv

this is the opencv code：

```
int main()  
{  
IplImage* image=cvLoadImage("C:\\boat.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

cout<<"1-norm is : "<<cvNorm(image,NULL,CV_L1)<<endl;  

cout<<"2-norm is : "<<cvNorm(image,NULL,CV_L2)<<endl;  //the result is 6000+，it's too
big and unnormal!

return 0;
}
```

The l2 norm result is so big,that is 6000+,however, the matlab answer is 229 as below,

This is the matlab code：

```
>> norm(image)

ans =

229.7975
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary, 6000+ norm for a grayscale image looks normal. Grayscale image values range from 0 to 255, so depending on the size of the image, even for images as small as 64x64, you may get `L2=sqrt(sum(image.^2))` (not an actual code) in thousands, tens of thousands or more.

More interesting is why `norm(image)` in Matlab is so low. `norm` does not accept `uint8` vectors, so somewhere between loading image and calculating its norm there is a data conversion that may also have a side effect of changing absolute values in image, and subsequently its norm.

Comment: THX！I have used im2double(image) in matlab, so the  image values range from 0 to 1.